# SIGSEGV when calling mmap twice

Tags: c, linux, gcc, mmap, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to run the following program on Ubuntu, but it crashes with segmentation fault.

What I'm trying to do is call mmap twice:

```
p1 = mmap(null, size: 16 * 4k, offset: 0);
p2 = mmap(p1+(16*4K), 136 * 4k , offset: 16 * 4k);
```

Basically, trying to create two consecutive memory regions mirroring two consecutive regions in a file.
It is okay if the 2nd mmap would fail, but I would like to understand why it is causing a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd, ret;
    void* p1;
    void* p2;
    unlink ("test.file");// don't care if it doesn't exists

    fd = open("test.file", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_SYNC, ALLPERMS);

    if(fd == -1)
        return errno;

    ret = ftruncate(fd, 4096*16);
    if(ret != 0)
        return errno;

    p1 = mmap(NULL, 4096*16, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if(p1 == (void*)-1)
        return errno;

    ret = ftruncate(fd, 4096*150);
    if(ret != 0)
        return errno;

    // dies here!
    p2 = mmap(p1 + (4096*16), 4096*(150-16), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED |MAP_FIXED, fd, 4096*16);
    if(p2 == (void*)-1)
        return errno;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may allocate guard pages before and after your mapping to prevent from overflowing your mapping, they are supposed to segfault on read and write. Another option is that you hit the guard page under the stack. Check `pmap` output after the first `mmap` to be sure.

Try using `mremap` instead.

Comment: Hi Maxim, thank you very much, can you point me to some resources to get more information about this?

Comment: @AyendeRahien I was able to reproduce it, but not any more with the original source code. Could be address space randomization.